# Using a varchar(MAX) or a varbinary(MAX) to store an length-undefined string within SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, content-management-system, blogs

I am making a CMS of sorts and, of course, it will have a blog. So, this might be a pretty noob question, but, from a database optimization point of view, would you use a varchar(max) or a varbinary(max) to store the body of a blog post?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use an `NVarChar(MAX)` myself, to account for Unicode too; but you can certainly use `VarChar(MAX)` if you don't need Unicode. `VarBinary` would be more for if you had non-text data. You could also use `Text` or `NText`, but those have been deprecated since sql2005.

Comment: is there not any significant storage size advantage if you convert the string to binary?

Comment: Unless you are compressing it no, there is not. The VarChar(MAX) data type (which, by the way, is totally different from the regular VarChar(x) type) is made for storing and retrieving lots of text.